# One of three if - cases in a while loop does not seem to work, while the other two do?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to write a little program in Java that lets the user enter four Strings (username, email, password, passcheck).

The program is supposed to check if these strings fulfill certain conditions in a `while` loop, which asks the user to enter the strings mentioned above, until they fulfill these conditions.

The program compiles and the first two `if` cases seem to work fine. Only the comparisin between the two passwords (`password` and `passcheck`) seems to be wrong. Even if I enter the same String twice, they do not pass the comparison, and I have no idea why this is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Registry {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Dialogue for the user to fill
        System.out.println("Please enter your username (at least 5 characters)");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid emailadress (an @ is necessary for it to pass.)");
        String email = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter two matching passwords, so we can make sure that you entered them correctly.");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();
        String passcheck = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean user = false;
        boolean mail = false;
        boolean pass = false;

        // Error messages within a loop in order to make the user enter valid arguments.
        while (user != true && mail != true && pass != true){
            if ((username == "" || username.length() < 5) || (username == " " || username.length() < 5)) {
                System.out.println("Username is empty or does not have enough characters! Please enter another.");
                username = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            else{
                user = true;
            }

            if (email.contains("@") == false){
                System.out.println("Invalid Mailadress. Please enter again.");
                email = scanner.nextLine();
            }

            else{
                mail = true;
            }

            if(password == passcheck){
                pass = true;
            }
            else if {

                System.out.println("Your passwords do not match. Please enter them correctly.");
                password = scanner.nextLine();
                passcheck = scanner.nextLine();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(password.equals(passcheck)){
        pass = true;
    }
```

with `==` you compare the object references and not the values.

Furthermore you can simplify this:

```
if ((username == "" || username.length() < 5) || (username == " " || username.length() < 5)) {
```

to

```
if (username.trim().length() < 5) {
```

Comment: I see, that did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't `username.trim().length() < 5` cover `"".equals(username.trim())` ?

Comment: no I would say username.trim().length() == 0 covers "".equals.

Comment: What I mean is, `(("".equals(username.trim()) || username.trim().length() < 5))` is logically equivalent to just `(username.trim().length() < 5)`, since zero is less than 5.

Answer (score 3):

You have another issue in your loop beside wrong String comparison.

```
while (user != true && mail != true && pass != true)
```

means that the loop will terminate once any one of the three boolean flags is true.

What you want is probably

```
while (user != true || mail != true || pass != true)
```

which means the loop will only terminate when all three flags are true.

Or even better :

```
while (!user || !mail || !pass)
```

Comment: good point thats also an open issue...

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `Strings` using `==` instead of `equals`.

Try using something like this:

```
"".equals(username) //...
```